# Monotone non-(in)decreasing sequences of subsets of $\Omega$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

**Proposition**
Let $\{A_n:n\geq1\}$ be a sequence of subsets of $\Omega$. Show that

$$
\begin{align}
&1)\;\text{If}\;A_k\subset A_{k+1}\;\text{for all}\;k\in\mathbb{N},\text{then}\;\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\\
&2)\;\text{If}\;A_k\supset A_{k+1}\;\text{for all}\;k\in\mathbb{N},\text{then}\;\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\\
\end{align}
$$

**1)** If $A_k\subset A_{k+1}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\{A_n:n\geq1\}\uparrow A$, *i.e.* the sequence is monotone non-decreasing. In such a case we have that $\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_m \overset{?}{=} A_n$. In other words, if

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} A_n&=A_*\\
&=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_n\\
&=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{m=n}^\infty A_m\\
&=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy To be honest, I have trouble to justify the last transformation. It was more guessing on my part. What’s the interpretation of the limit of a sequence of subsets?

Comment: $\liminf A_n =\cap_{n=1}^{\infty } \cup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k$ and $\limsup A_n =\cup_{n}{^\infty } \cap_{k=n}^{\infty }A_k$; we say $\{A_k\}$ converges if $\limsup A_n =\liminf A_n $.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok, that makes sense to me. But what's the story behind $\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_m \overset{?}{=} A_n$?

Comment: it is correct: $A_n \subset A_m$ for all $m \geq n$ so $A_n \subset \cap_{m \geq n} A_m$ and the reverse inclusion is obvious.

Comment: Thanks, you’re a great teacher and can explain very well!